# Visual Studio complains about typescript errors that tsc and eslint don't

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

This morning, I restarted my computer and opened visual studio code and got this error I've never had before:

[image]

I did not change any code in my project (i.e., `git status` is empty). I'm not sure if this started today, or I just never noticed those files and it's been happening for a while. But I'm certain these errors weren't showing 5 days ago, and the erroring code has been there longer than that. Here is that code:

```js
        } catch (e) {
            if (typeof e === "string") {
                throw new Error(
                    `...: ${e}`
                );
            } else {
                e.message = `... ${e.message}`;
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

If I run `tsc` or `eslint`, neither complain about this error. I want vscode to report what tsc/eslint would, not decide its own type checking rules. How do I get rid of these errors?

I don't know what I don't know. I guess I'll just attach my settings:

### user

```json
{
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "docker.showStartPage": false,
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "[json]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "typescript.tsserver.experimental.enableProjectDiagnostics": true
}
```

I toggled `typescript.tsserver.experimental.enableProjectDiagnostics`, and it has no effect on this error message.

### workspace

```json
{
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook"
    },
    "notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
        "default": "right",
        "jupyter-notebook": "left"
    },
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "eslint.workingDirectories": [
    "./firebase/functions",
    ],
    "eslint.format.enable": false,
    "prettier.enable": true,
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[jsonc]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
    },
    "typescript.format.semicolons": "insert",
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "prettier.configPath": "firebase/functions/.prettierrc.json",
}
```

Here is a censored version of my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "...",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "build": "tsc --build .",
    "test": "npm run lint && npm run build && ...",
    ...
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/testing": "^0.20.8",
    "@types/child-process-promise": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/follow-redirects": "^1.13.0",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.5.7",
    "@types/progress": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/request": "^2.48.7",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.10.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.5",
    "eslint": "^7.31.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mocha": "^8.1.3",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
    ...
  },
  "private": true
}
```

(a lot of unrelated-to-this-problem weirdness in this file. sorry; it's legacy and I'm working on improving it).

Here's my tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": ".",
    },
    "files": [],
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "./src"
        },
        {
            "path": "./test"
        },
    ]
}
```

Note: this file is in `./firebase/functions`, not the project root.

Here's the `./firebase/functions/src/tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "../lib",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "target": "es2019",
    "composite": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "types": ["node", ...],
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

Here's the `./firebase/functions/test/tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "../libtest",
    "strict": false,
    "composite": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

How do I get visual studio code to report the same errors as my tsc and eslint -- no more, no less?

Comment: This is because it doesn't know what type it's expecting.  Try adding type to your catch and see if that helps!

Comment: @3xGuy thank you for the help. I am aware that would fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vs code is apparently using a more recent version of typescript than your package.json has, and as a result it's using a new option that the error in catch blocks be treated as `unknown` instead of `any`. To fix this, look at the bottom right of your vs code window and you should see the typescript version, something like this:

[image]

Click the version number and a dropdown will appear at the top of the screen

[image]

Click "Select Typescript Version" to change it.

Usually, vs code is able to figure out your workspace's version and will list that as a possibility. If for some reason it can't, or if you want to use a different version, you can tell typescript what to do with the "typescript.tsdk" setting. For information on how to set that up, see this page: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-the-workspace-version-of-typescript

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. Can you mention something about how you'll only find other versions if you set the `typescript.tsdk` workspace setting?